# Wiring for 10000W 220V SCR Voltage Regulator Speed Controller

Tags: voltage-regulator, wiring, scr

I live in the US and have the Twist Lock Electrical Plug 4 Wire, 30 Amps, 125/250V, NEMA L14-30P. It has 2 hots, 1 ground, and 1 neutral wire. I saw the following scr controller on ebay and am confused how one might do the wiring. There's a wiring diagram on the side of the picture.

Am I supposed to combine 2 hots IN, shared neutral for both IN and OUT (COM slot), and 2 hot wires from OUT?

I'm used to the controllers that have 4 slots, 2 hots IN and 2 hots OUT.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, a 30 A plug is NOT SUFFICIENT for a 220 V, 10 KW controller.  You should be using a 50 A plug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - this is European style, where they run 220 instead of 120, so they only need one phase - a hot and a neutral.  Here we use two phases (2 hots) for 220, so you can't get there safely.  See if the seller makes a US version.

Answer (score 0):

That is a single-phase controller as clearly indicated by the diagram on the side. From your "2 hots" description it sounds as though you have a two-phase + neutral supply. If you combine two hots in you will short circuit the phases together.

You need to either get two of these - one for each phase - or get a two-phase controller. If getting two the control side inputs can probably be wired in parallel but you haven't provided enough info to assess that fully.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feuEug.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have the device in use as a controller for a 120 volt quartz tower heater. The unit is designed to be in series with the load and is in reality a two terminal device the common terminal being unused in the circuit (thus the broken line on the diagram). The common terminal is just a tie point so you don't need a wire nut. For 220v use just consider one line as a return.